# Can I fake a namespace reference in XSLT

Tags: visual-studio, xslt

I have a xsl that i've copied out of Sharepoint, and pulled into visual studio.

Visual studio will not compile or apply the transfromation because of this error

```
XslTransformException
---------------------
Cannot find the script or external object that implements prefix 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime'.
```

Can I tell VS to ignore the prefix? Or somehow provide a dummy schema to get the XSLT to work?

I was think of just removing all the references, editing my transform and then maybe put them back if I need them.

Comment: Seems your XSLT references external extensions. Without seeing the relevant XSLT how should we know what happens when you remove the reference?

Comment: I thought i could do without the extensions- but after more checking i realise that they are more involved in the transformation than i first thought.

Comment: You could try to find the extensions on the SharePoint server. They are most likely either contained in an assembly (.dll) or in other XSLT file as script.